# Does changes backgorund in theme file cause problems to images?

Tags: codenameone

I made  some changes on boackground color to theme.res and all all of sudden my stoped working.
I check the debbuging console and showed me that could not find an images from res.

I tried to open gui builder but it did not open. So I deleted the component that used this image from the xxxx.gui file.

My app start working and crashes again on another point that needs another image.

Gui builder still is not working.

Any help is aprecciated

Comment: It sounds like something got corrupted and the res file is now broken. It's probably too late. You need to retrace the steps that lead you here and reproduce the issue consistently while running with the console https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-track-designer-guibuilder-issues.html

Comment: I thinks this maut be the case. Do you know if images inside res files, are storing with their bytes or just the location path is stored and only during the build the real bytes of the images are stored?

Comment: The bytes are stored into the resource file

Comment: It seems that it was a corrupted file. I copy this project from another pc. When I copy it again I did not has any problems.